# Remove 'vendor' folder in React Native project root

Tags: ruby, react-native

I hadn't created new RN project in a while and after did some Ruby update and path configuration, I see in my new RN project there is *vendor* folder in the root.

[image]

Without it (tried renaming/deleting the folder) I get this error:

```
Could not find proper version of cocoapods (1.11.3) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

[image]

I did git pull from another laptop and tried to run `pod install` from ios folder, it doesn't require `bundle install` and runs well. How to get the same behavior with no 'vendor' folder in the project root?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is expected behavior (see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/32303). The `vendor` directory holds project dependencies (like 3rd party files and other code your project references that you didn't write). It is common for things like install commands (which fetch dependencies) to store content the project needs to reference in this directory so it's locally available to the project. It is also common best practice to add vendor paths to the project's git ignore file to ensure dependency code is not committed with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I installed both RVM and rbenv which is bad idea. I uninstalled RVM and I fixed the bundler and cocoapods from:

```
cd ~
gem install bundler
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
gem install cocoapods
```

I removed 'vendor' folder and go to ios folder and did 'pod install'. Now it's working fine, it doesn't generate 'vendor' folder.

Comment: But still, initializing new project with `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeApp` still generates 'vendor' folder. Not sure why.

Comment: It's by design; it's ensuring that the correct version of ruby will be downloaded and made locally available to the project. https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/discussions/411